# How do I get selected rows when grid control is bound to BindingSource?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-6.0, bindingsource, devexpress-gridcontrol

I typically use this code to retrieve data when the grid control data source is bonded to the data table

```
        private void AddSelectedRowsToList()
        {
            var selectedRows = gridView1.GetSelectedRows();
            for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.Length; i++)
            {
                var row = (gridView1.GetRow(selectedRows[i]) as DataRowView).Row;

                string firstName = row["FirstName"].ToString();
                string lastName = row["LastName"].ToString();

                usersInfo.Add(new SAPSUserInfo(firstName, lastName));
            }
        }
```

As soon as I bonded grid control data source to BindingSource, I got this error

> System.NullReferenceException   HResult=0x80004003
> Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

On this line

```
var row = (gridView1.GetRow(selectedRows[i]) as DataRowView).Row;
```

**How do I get selected rows when grid control is bound to BindingSource?**
Update
This the type of my BindingSource

```
private readonly BindingSource listEmployeeDto = new();
```

Comment: A preciese answer depend on which data source is behind BindingSource in your case. Is it DataTable? The obvious cause of the issue, is that the GetRow method did not return a DataRowView instance. So you can use a debugger to find out which type it has

Comment: The binding source is IEnumerable<EmployeeDto> and the GetRow method return EmployeeDto

Answer (score 0):

thanks to [Nikita K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2470658/nikita-k) this is how I solved it

```
private void AddSelectedRowsToList()
{
    var selectedRows = gridView1.GetSelectedRows();
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.Length; i++)
    {
        var employeeDto = gridView1.GetRow(selectedRows[i]) as EmployeeDto;
        
        usersInfo.Add(new SAPSUserInfo(employeeDto.FirstName,employeeDto.LastName));
    }

}
```